# Как задать несколько значений в одну переменную и после что бы они были по порядку в действии?

Tags: bash, sh

#Место

```
/Volumes/Внешний диск какой нибудь не важно.
```

#Имя файлов внутри около 90 штук

```
com.apple.Москва.plist
com.apple.Мытищи.plist
com.apple.Тверь.plist
com.apple.Чехов.plist
```

#Вопрос
#Каким образом можно каждый файл который находится в этой папке поместить в ПАПКИ на рабочем столе с такими же названиями файлов? Москва Мытищи Тверь Чехов?

#Я образно представляю так:

```
comFILES=("Москва", "Мытыщи", "Тверь", "Чехов") #все названия около 90 файлов
link="/Volumes/Внешний диск"
```

#а после

```
for f in $link 
        Скопировать com.apple.$comFILES.plist рабочий стол по папкам c такими же именами которые уже там есть. то есть $comFILES.
    # то есть даже зрительно что бы переменная была одинаковым именем и там и там ~/Desktop $comFILES
```

Что бы имя из `$comFILES` копировалось в соответствующую такому же названию папке на рабочем столе.. `$comFILES`
#Вроде не так сложно но оказалось очень сложно (((...

Либо наоборот с другой стороны пойти

```
`if` на рабочем столе есть папки с именами из списка `$comFILES`то из папки `$link` копируются файлы com.$comFILES.plist
```

Файл москва в папку москву итд

Answer (score 1):

Пусть в текущей директории у нас лежат файлы:

```
com.apple.Москва.plist
com.apple.Мытищи.plist
com.apple.Тверь.plist
```

Запустим следующий скрипт:

```bash
for f in com.apple.*.plist; do
  filename="${f%.plist}"
  directory="${filename#com.apple.}"
  mkdir -p "$directory"
  cp "$f" "$directory"
done
```

После запуска этого скрипта в текущей директории будут созданы файлы:

```
Москва/com.apple.Москва.plist
Мытищи/com.apple.Мытищи.plist
Тверь/com.apple.Тверь.plist
```

Comment: Спасибо всем участвовавшим, получилось с первым вариантом, но вот только спустя 3 дня получилось.. Там еще тонкости оказались и получилось что не до конца была описана проблема, но всё решилось всё равно с помощью первого метода, (Доработанного под мою ситуацию) Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
in=/tmp/test
out=$(systemd-path user-desktop)
ls "$in"/com.apple.*.plist |awk -v out="$out" -F. '{OUT="\x27"out"\x27/"$(NF-1);system("mkdir -p "OUT";cp -u "$0" "OUT)}'
```

`in` - путь к папке где лежат исходные файлы com.apple.Москва.plist ...

`out` - папка рабочего стола

`\x27` - аналогичен "'", добавляем экранированных кавычек что поможет избежать ошибок если в названии папки рабочего стола есть пробелы

Answer (score 0):

Для вашей задачи удобней сделать цикл не по конкретным файлам а по названиям городов, как-то так:

```
comFILES=("Москва" "Мытыщи" "Тверь" "Чехов")
link="/Volumes/Внешний диск"

shopt -s nullglob
for item in "${comFILES}"; do
    cp "$link/"*"$item"* "desktop/$item/"
done
```